# which bitbucket server api suits to copy pr from repo to another repo?

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket, devops

My objective is to sync changes between all 4 repos such as "web, android, iOS & config", having config as the single source of truth.

Now of course each and every individual platform repo has its content, but at the root, there will be a repo that has the exact same content, so:

- root of web will have a folder "config", where the content is exactly similar to "config" repo
- root of android will have a folder "config", where the content is exactly similar to "config" repo
- etc

Now developer will only make changes to the repo "config", and upon pr successfully merged, i wish to create PR in "web.config,android.config & iOS.config" individually.

I do realized that bitbucket provides documentation for their API, however im not exactly sure which exact API suits my needs.

My best guess is i will have this script, being triggered upon pr merged successfully, then we can query the last commit of master branch by running the below command

```sh
curl -u username:password https://bitbucket.xx.xxx.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/config/branches/default
# {"id":"refs/heads/master","displayId":"master","type":"BRANCH","latestCommit":"afff780e4xxxxxxxx","latestChangeset":"afff780e4xxxxxxxxx","isDefault":true}
```

Now that i successfully has the `latestCommit`, i can then query the changes?

```sh
curl -u username:password https://bitbucket.xx.xxx.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/config/commits/afff780e4xxxxxxxx
```

in which i have tons of metadata, but im not sure what to do with them in order to proceed and create a new PR in other repos. Appreciated if anyone can shed some lights on this